# Using a Case Statement With IS NULL and IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    userName,
    CASE userName
    WHEN (userName IS NULL) THEN 'was null'
        WHEN (userName IS NOT NULL) THEN 'was not null'
    END AS caseExpressionTest
FROM
    top_users
```

This does not give me the results I want. When the value is not null, I get 'was null', and when actually is null, I get an actual MYSQL NULL value. What I want is that when userName is null, return 'was null' and when userName is not null, return 'was not null'. What am I doing wrong here?

I am purposefully trying to do this with CASE expression, not an IF or IFNULL expression.
Using MYSQL 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `case` expression.  There are two forms.  The form you want is:

```
(CASE WHEN userName IS NULL THEN 'was null'
      WHEN userName IS NOT NULL THEN 'was not null'
 END) AS caseExpressionTest
```

Note:  There is no `userName` after the `CASE`.

This checks each condition stopping at the first.

MySQL interprets booleans as a valid value.  So your version is either:

```
-- when userName is NULL
(CASE userName
    WHEN 0 THEN 'was null'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'was not null'
END AS caseExpressionTest
```

This will return `NULL`.

Or:

```
-- when userName is not NULL
(CASE userName
    WHEN 1 THEN 'was null'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'was not null'
END AS caseExpressionTest
```

Presumably, `userName` is a string.  This will convert `userName` to an integer based on leading digits.  If there are no leading digits, you get `0`, which is why there is a match.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying response. I was able to get it working.

Your answer shows that I was misinterpreting the CASE syntax and its two forms in the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case). I am still unclear about it, but things are working. I will post another question to clarify more.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    userName,
    CASE WHEN userName IS NULL THEN 'was null' else 'was not null' END AS caseExpressionTest
FROM
    top_users
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table top_users (userid int, userName varchar(50));
 insert into top_users values(1,'user1');
 insert into top_users(userid) values(2);
```

Query:

```
 SELECT 
         userid, 
         userName,
         CASE WHEN userName IS NULL THEN 'was null' else 'was not null' END AS caseExpressionTest
     FROM
         top_users
```

Output:

| userid | userName | caseExpressionTest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | was not null |
| 2 | <emnull</em | was null |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1550445829a348c43c5699a25d08fc03)*

Comment: That is an interesting way of doing it, thanks. I appreciate the db fiddle, too.