# Test CASE Expression Value Against NULL Or Not NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I am trying to understand the first form of CASE syntax from the mysql docs when working with NULL values. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case

The form is:

```
CASE value WHEN compare_value THEN result [WHEN compare_value THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END
```

(If I am right) In this form, each conditional is tested to see whether it matches the `value`.

But how to compare the `value` to null?

I tried this but receive a syntax error:

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    userName,
    CASE userName
      WHEN IS NULL THEN 'was null'
      WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN 'was not null'
    END
FROM
    top_users
```

I have it working as the second form of the CASE expression which does not have a `value`, but I am trying to understand the CASE expression fully.

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    userName,
    CASE 
      WHEN userName IS NULL THEN 'was null'
      WHEN userName IS NOT NULL THEN 'was not null'
    END
FROM
    top_users
```

How can I test whether userName is null or not null in the FIRST form of CASE expression? I am trying to not use an ELSE clause because there may be more conditions I need to add later.

Comment: . . The answer is that you cannot.  `NULL` does not match any value (even itself) and that is true in a `case` expression.  You need to use the searched `case`, as I recommended in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Case Statement With IS NULL and IS NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851970/using-a-case-statement-with-is-null-and-is-not-null)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks again. I separated the questions because the original resulted from not separating the two CASE forms, so I asked a separate question about the first form in particular for clarification.